# Tengo una duda sobre el sistema de reset password de django

Tags: python, django, email

Estoy aprendiendo a usar `django` y mi duda es si es posible cambiar el sistema para reestablecer la contraseña de los usuarios, el sistema por defecto de enviar un link por correo no lo quiero usar, mi idea es mandar un código para poder reestablecer la contraseña, pero no sé como se tendría que hacer y si es posible, también necesitaría saber si es seguro.

Lo que quiero es que el usuario que quiera recuperar su contraseña vaya a la sección de recuperación, rellene con su correo y presione enviar y se habilite un campo para poner el código que se le envié al correo.

No sé como tendría que hacerlo o ¿existe algún paquete para esto?.

Muchas gracias gente un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

lo que planteas no es necesario, cuando tu envías el correo al usuario creas un código único para el ingreso  uidb64=uid token=token, este codigo se valida en el template con {% if validlink %} de forma que el usuario solo tiene que reiniciar su password. por cierto dicho código tiene un vencimiento.